# Add Overlay Element on top of VLC Player in Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, libvlc

I am creating an app using Ionic Framework. In my app I am using cordova VLC Player (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-libvlc). Everything is working fine but now I want to put an overlay over VLC Player. When I click on video it opens VLC player in full screen mode and I cannot do anything. I just want to add an overlay over VLC so I can show text or anything on top of the video.

```
window.libVLCPlayer.play(video_link, options, this.onSuccess, this.onFail);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!